# Android - Stroke looks pixelated at the corners of a rounded rectangle

Tags: android, stroke

Why is the stroke at the corners of the rectangle so ugly? If I draw the shape in xml, it works fine (at least it works in activities, I could not test it with a widget).

```
Paint strokePaint = new Paint();
strokePaint.setARGB(255, 16, 23, 131);
strokePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
strokePaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
```

[image]

I am testing on hdpi density. Has anyone met this problem?

Comment: how did you do the rounded corners in this code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with:

```
strokePaint.setAntiAlias(true)
```